# how to add line break in files?

Tags: c

How to add line break in c for files? The task is to get string And store it in file. While displaying it should print each string in new line. I have tried to add strcat (str,"\r\n") and also fprintf(fp,"%s\n",str) before writing each string to file.. But it displays empty.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct ch
{
    char his[1000];
}s;
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    clrscr();
    fp=fopen("str.txt","r+");
    rewind(fp);
    strcat(s.his,"text");
    fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,fp);
    fprintf(fp,"%s\n",s.his);
    strcat(s.his,"new");
    fwrite(&s,sizeof(s),1,fp);
    rewind(fp);
    while(1)
    {
        fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,fp);
        if(feof(fp))
            break;
        printf("%s",s.his);
    }
    getch();
}
Expected Output:
text
new
```

Output i am getting just blank.

Comment: Have you heard about indenting code to make it readable?

Comment: its alrdy indented.

Comment: strcat(s.his,"text"); s.his has not been initialized. This invokes undefined behaviour, please initialize it before working with it.

Comment: what is type of `his[1000]` ??????

Comment: It does not appear to be so - perhaps change tabs to spaces?

Comment: @robin.koch `s` is initialized. Because `s` is global variable.

Comment: the data type for his is char.

Comment: Does `str.txt` exist, or is the `fopen` failing?  Omitting error checking for the purpose of simplifying an example is sometime laudable, other times it is the root of all evil.

Comment: You write "text" followed by 996 zeros (perhaps more, if there is any padding), then you write "text" followed by a newline then "textnew" followed by 993 zeros.  Stop writing all the zeros.  And don't use `feof` like this.  It is incorrect, and your code will enter an infinite loop on a read error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Best to only use `fread()/fwrite()` when opening files in binary mode. `"rb+"`.  For this task use text more and `fprintf()`/ `fgets()` to write /read the text file.  UV for a better than usual first time presentation of a problem.

Comment: After opening the file, test if `fp == NULL`.  `"r+"` expects the file to exist.  Is that the problem?  Try using `"wb+"` to create a new file.

Comment: Your first `fwrite()` writes 1000 bytes, of which 4 are letters and 996 are null bytes.  Your first `fprintf()` then adds 5 more bytes, 4 letters and newline (or probably 6 bytes since you're probably on Windows, as it converts the newline in the string to CRLF).  Your second `fwrite` writes another 1000 bytes, 7 letters and 993 null bytes.  Your file contains `"text"`, nulls, `"text`", newline, `"textnew"`, nulls. You don't force out a newline at the end of the reading cycle (but should). Remember, `fwrite()` and `fread()` are for writing and reading binary data and care nothing about lines.